# Change td height based on it's content

Tags: html, css, web-development-server

[image]

[image]

```
   <tr> 
        <td data-label='Position'>Sales Representative</td>
        <td data-label='Tel Num.'>0</td> 
        So on and so forth...
   </tr>

     table td::before {
          content: attr(data-label);
          position:absolute;
          left:0;
          width:50%;
          text-align:left;
     }
     table td{
          padding-left: 50%;
          position:relative;
          text-align:right;
     }
```

The left side of the first photo is causing the left side to overflow and not automatically adjust its height.

The right side is what I want to achieve(edited through photoshop)
The second photo word-wrapped because the content itself overflowed not the header content

I want the height of the td to auto-adjust both on the ::before(header) and the actual content(data) if there is a word wrap

Comment: please add your code.